# ms access - 3 table join w/ complex JOIN condition on third table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to join multiple tables in access. 
Access has some odd syntax when it comes to joins, and I cant seem to get this right

In particular, C needs to consider fields from both A and B

```
 select a.*, B.*, c.* 
  from 
  (tblOne as A 
   Left join tblTwo as B on  A.ParentId = B.Id )
   left join tblThree as C on C.ParentId = B.Id and C.ShoeSize = A.ShoeSize
```

I have encountered and gotten past putting each Parens thing when more than 2 tables are involved. 
I can join in C as long as I only want to refer to 1 of the other tables. 
This type thing is fairly straight forward in SQL Server. 
Any help would be appreciated, I cant seem to find an answer on google.

The client is currently using ms Access 2003. If the problem can be remedied by a newer version, I am pretty I could talk them into an upgrade.

thanks

greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the following in Access 2010 and it *seems* to work, although I must admit that I don't have a clear picture in my mind as to how this might be used in the "real world"...

```
SELECT ab.*, c.* 
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.ID AS ID1, a.ShoeSize AS ShoeSize1, b.ID AS ID2 
    FROM tblOne a LEFT JOIN tblTwo b 
        ON a.ParentId = b.Id
) ab LEFT JOIN tblThree c 
    ON c.ParentId = ab.ID2 and c.ShoeSize = ab.ShoeSize1
```

Comment: the third table is really a tally table. Im outer joining on the 2nd table multiple times and need the tally table as a control. This all seemed to muddy the issue so I simplified... Let me find a copy of 2010, if it works there, super!

Comment: @greg Okay, thanks for clarifying. I tested my query in Access 2010 because I had it at hand, but I don't see why it wouldn't work with Access 2003. However, if you want an excuse to get your client to upgrade to something newer (and supported).... ;)

Comment: i downloaded 2010 on my local machine this limitation seems to have gone away.